# ? operator in sscanf regular expression

Tags: c, c-strings, ansi-c

I'm trying to parse an extension out of a list of files of the format 'filename.extension'.  However in the cases where filename is blank, I'm getting undesired results.

For example....

```
sscanf(my_string,"%*[^.].%s",file_ext);
```

Will properly parse the below

```
foo.gif such that file_ext = gif 
bar.jpg such that file_ext = jpg
```

However it will fail to parse cases where the prefixed filename is missing. i.e.

```
.pdf will result in file_ext = NULL
```

I've tried to use the ? operator after ] to indicate the string may or may not exist; however it's clearly not supported in C.  Is there another solution or something I'm overlooking? Thanks!

Comment: `scanf` format strings are *not* regular expressions. You can only use them for a very limited parsing. You better read the whole string, then validate/parse by other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard string function `strchr` to determine whether a point is present and then use `strcpy` to copy the file extension. For example

```
char *p = strchr( my_string, '.' );
if ( p != NULL ) strcpy( file_ext, p + 1 );
```

Or you can use `strrchr` that finds the last occurrence of a character.

```
char *p = strrchr( my_string, '.' );
if ( p != NULL ) strcpy( file_ext, p + 1 );
```